# How to fix /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: line 261: log_success_msg: command not found?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I was facing this error after I installed xampp in my linux manjaro. Previously even with this error, first time I opened phpmyadmin and do some query it is doing fine. But somehow the phpmyadmin show blank white screen. How do I fix it?
[image: my error]

**UPDATE**:
The blank screen is no more, but the warning code is still present. The warning code did nothing to my productivity. But still, it is a bit bothering me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with phpMyAdmin and I resolved doing:

[1] `sudo nvim /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and changing this line:

```php
// instead of localhost
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

[2] Changing in my browser the URL from `localhost/phpmyadmin` to `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`

This worked for me, hope to help someone.

Comment: I'm sorry for really late answer, been switching project with different language that I forgot ever asked this question. 
Actually, I tried reinstalled my xampp and the blank screen is no more, but the warning code is still present. I did what you suggest, but the warning code still present. It does not effect anything though. But still, a bit bothered everytime I start my xampp

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem simply by removing the log_success_msg function call in /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server at line 261, not the most elegant solution, but simple. It is worth noting that this edit does not affect the functionality.

```
wait_for_ready () {
      i=0
      while test $i -ne $service_startup_timeout ; do
    
        if $bindir/mysqladmin ping >/dev/null 2>&1; then
          log_success_msg // ***Delete this function call***
          return 0
        elif kill -0 $! ; then
          :  # mysqld_safe is still running
        else
          # mysqld_safe is no longer running, abort the wait loop
          break
        fi
    
        echo $echo_n ".$echo_c"
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        sleep 1
    
      done
    
      log_failure_msg

  return 1
}
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the LBS module, since the script uses it to display messages, as mentioned in the documentation of `/opt/lamp/bin/mysql.server` line 93

```
# Use LSB init script functions for printing
# messages, if possible
```